# Xcode How to build for a device with iOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I have a device with iOS 5.0, and I am trying to install my app with XCode 4.0, but even the version 4.1 that is on developers.apple mentions that it only supports SDK 4.3 which is what I am developing with at the moment and is the latest version for XCode, how can I build for SDK 5.0?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must accept the "Updated Program License Agreement" and you can then access to the "iOS SDK GM seed" to download XCode 4.2

Answer (score 1):

You cant build it straight to your device but you can use ad hoc and then install it on your iOS 5 device